# Java8 null check collection before add element

Tags: java-8

I have an entity. Some times the inner collection of **info** elements not get created. So to implementing correspond method I need null checking.

```
public class Tag {
    ...
    private Set<ProjectInfo> projectInfoSet;
    ...

    public void addProjectInfo(ProjectInfo projectInfo) {
    if (this.projectInfoSet == null) {
        this.projectInfoSet = new HashSet<>();
    }
    this.projectInfoSet.add(projectInfo);
    }
}
```

I believe Java8 provides better solution. For example using **Optional** class. But i'm not sure if it is good to use **Optional** in my **entity** class. Other case possible I do not need here optional, because I need to create *projectInfoSet*, it should like *behavioral pattern strategy*.

Can someone recommend the better implementation way or explanations how it could be done in better way.

Comment: Is there a reason not to initialize that member when you declare it? `private Set<ProjectInfo> projectInfoSet = new HashSet<>();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add initial value to your field and forget about null-check:

```
public class Tag {
    ...
    private Set<ProjectInfo> projectInfoSet = new HashSet<>();
    ...

    public void addProjectInfo(ProjectInfo projectInfo) {
        this.projectInfoSet.add(projectInfo);
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried do it, but if controller gets json with empty field, i do not have here collection, so i have removed default initialization here than. Do you think i should consider my json convertation issue and fix it?

Answer (score 2):

If you are using jackson you can use a configuration parameter to initialiase it ?

Like this here

```
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getSerializationConfig().setSerializationInclusion(Inclusion.NON_DEFAULT);
```